# Change blank fields in .doc file. WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ms-word, ms-office

I have a .doc document. In this document i have some blanks for data. For example:

```
"car_id" is the best car in "car_country".
```

I need to open this doc file and change this blanks (`"car_id", "car_country"`) to data from some object.


How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This web page has some very good samples of Word automation using C#. Specifically, look at section 6 in the web page for a Mail Merge example.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would use DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll. You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124). OpenXMLSDKv2.msi will add assembly. You will just need to add reference to DocumentFormat.OpenXml. And the OpenXMLSDKTool.msi will install a usefull tool that will display xml structure of .docx (for example) document.